# Terminal font looks different (I think some application changed it)

Tags: windows, terminal, fonts

The `Terminal` font on my computer (Windows 8) is messed up. I think some application I had from earlier changed it to look different.

Looks fine in the CMD:

[image]

Everywhere else, ugly:

[image]

So, how do I restore the font to its former glory?

Comment: It’s a bitmap font, so it’s normal that it looks different when used in several sizes (bitmaps don’t match).

Comment: @Fitoschido It looks like the one in CMD on everyone else's computer at the same size. Also, it just fixed itself one day, making this question rather useless.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP comments that the problem fixed itself and can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is exclusively tied to notepad as in the screenshot, it's located in the `format` tab, and under `font`.

If your issue is system wide, then by default Windows reads the default font from `Appearance and Customization` and under `Fonts`. In there, if you go into `Font Settings` you can click `Restore default font settings`. This should return it back to normal.

Go into regedit then `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Font Substitutes` in there, go into the key `MS Shell Dlg` edit the string value and type in the name of your desired font e.g. `Times New Roman`. Also change `MS Shell Dlg 2` then do a reboot and you should be good to go.

Comment: It's not tied to notepad, and the `Restore default font settings` didn't work.

Comment: Try the second solution that I appended to the answer, let me know if that works for you. It is changing it for me.

Comment: Second solution didn't work either. Any others?

Comment: What in particular is changed? I'm trying to wrap my head around it. The font for like menus and things or what?

Comment: Everything except the CMD has the changed `Terminal` font. Flash games, notepad, etc.

Comment: Could you have disabled ClearType or messed around with DPI settings by mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the font cache at C:\Windows\system32\fntcache.dat.  This should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

It is because "Terminal" is not actually the font used for console. If my memory serves me well, the font you need is stored in "dosapp.fon" file, but it is not compatible with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've see this same situation happen in Windows 7 when given temporary admin rights on my laptop at work.

The 9-point terminal font, which I tend to use heavily in places like PuTTY windows and the like, changes size drastically from a font roughly similar to 9-point Fixed Sys to a very narrow font like the original person describes above.

No other fonts are impacted.  Just the 9-point Terminal font as far as I can see.

Things return to normal when I reboot the machines and my temporary admin rights go away.  So if the problem occurs with temporary admin privileges, the issue is temporary and rebooting fixes it.